# Find Specific number from list

Tags: string, oracle

I have millions records like this but im sharing here few records
what i need is just take 8 charchers from this recodrs so many have (.) and some have (/) so remove (.) abd (/) please see the sample output 
Records in Table

```
GBR.FCL.AT.245448C.A
GBR.FCL.AT.225405L.A
at286623da
EASA UK/AT/311969F/A
AT/332092H/A
AT238691G/A
```

Output should be like this

```
245448CA
225405LA
286623da
311969FA
332092HA
```

Comment: How to recognize the part of the string you need? Does it always start with AT? And are you sure that AT exactly occurs once per string? Or is it the only part of the string that contains a digit?

Comment: nope .......................

Comment: I can't get the point. How do you understand which part of the string you need to get?

Comment: for exmaply (GBR.FCL.AT.245448C.A) i need this part (245448CA)

Comment: The questions are still the same. How to recognize the part of the string you need? Does it always start with AT? And are you sure that AT exactly occurs once per string? Or is it the only part of the string that contains a digit? What if you have a string 'AT.AT.AT567AT456'? or if there is no AT in the string? or if you have ATXXXXXXXX? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we can rely on the sample as complete and representative (not always a safe assumption in SO) the desired output is the last eight characters of the string, ignoring `.` and `\`.

So the simplest thing that could possibly work would be to strip out the unwanted characters using `translate()` then return the last eight characters:

```
select substr(translate(str, 'a.\', 'a'), -8) as extracted_str
from your_table
```

A slightly more *engineered* solution would apply regex to fine a string of the format 999999AA:

```
select regexp_replace(translate(str, 'a.\', 'a'),
                   '^(.*)([[:digit:]]{6}[[:alpha:]]{2})(.*)$', '\2'
      ) as extracted_str
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to get 8 characters, excluding `/` and `.`, starting from the string `AT` ( no matter the case) and that there is exactly one occurrence of `AT` (in any case combination) in the input string, this should be what you need:

```
with input(x) as (
    select 'GBR.FCL.AT.245448C.A' from dual union all
    select 'GBR.FCL.AT.225405L.A' from dual union all
    select 'at286623da' from dual union all
    select 'EASA UK/AT/311969F/A' from dual union all
    select 'AT/332092H/A' from dual union all
    select 'AT238691G/A' from dual  
)
select x as yourString,
       substr(translate(x, 'x/.', 'x'), instr(translate(upper(x), '/.x', 'x'), 'AT')+2, 8) as result
from input
```

Which gives:

```
YOURSTRING           RESULT
-------------------- --------------------------------
GBR.FCL.AT.245448C.A 245448CA
GBR.FCL.AT.225405L.A 225405LA
at286623da           286623da
EASA UK/AT/311969F/A 11969FA
AT/332092H/A         332092HA
AT238691G/A          238691GA
```